# DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable

Tags: socket.io, video-streaming, webrtc, video-conferencing

I can't display the remote stream.
I added the localstream to peer connection but I can't display the remote stream because this issue.
"DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable"

```
if (signal.sdp) {
            connections[fromId].setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(signal.sdp)).then(() => {
                if (signal.sdp.type === 'offer') {
                    connections[fromId].createAnswer().then((description) => {
                        connections[fromId].setLocalDescription(description).then(() => {
                            socket.emit('signal', fromId, JSON.stringify({ 'sdp': connections[fromId].localDescription }));
                        }).catch(e => console.log(e));
                    }).catch(e => console.log(e));
                }
            }).catch(e => console.log(e));
        }

        if (signal.ice) {
            connections[fromId].addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(signal.ice)).catch(e => console.log(e));
        }
```